# Как осуществить выравнивание блоков по ширине изменением их размеров?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть код на https://codepen.io/osmanof-the-vuer/pen/ZErPezX.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 134px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  background: #abc;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">world</div>
  <div class="item">my</div>
  <div class="item">dear</div>
  <div class="item">friends</div>
</div>
```

На текущий момент блоки располагаются так:

[image: Текущий результат]

Я бы хотел, чтобы было что-то подобное:

[image: что я хочу]

То есть, чтобы изменялась ширина крайних блоков.
Спасибо!

Comment: `.item:last-child { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @ΝNL993 это повлияет только на один элемент из всего списка

Comment: @teran ну так разве не это нужно автору вопроса?

Comment: @ΝNL993 у него все элементы находятся в одном родительком флекс-диве, и флексом переносятся на строки. Ваше правило будет применяться только к последнему элемент в DOM. А ему надо, чтобы применялось к последним элементам в строках, которые к DOM отношения не имеют

Comment: @teran не понимаю откуда вы взяли эту информацию, в вопросе ничего такого не написано.

Comment: @ΝNL993 в вопросе приведена верстка и рисунок в котором растянуто не только `friends` но и `dear`., а если бы `friends` было бы очень длинными словом, то то растянулось бы `dear` и `world`

Comment: :last-child меняет лишь последний объект, в данном случае, "friends". Мне нужно, чтобы это были именно крайние, то есть каждой строчки. Спасибо за старания!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  column-gap: 5px;
  row-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 134px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  background: #abc;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px; 
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Hello</div>
  <div class="item">world</div>
  <div class="item">my</div>
  <div class="item">dear</div>
  <div class="item">friends</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Мне это помогло)